# PointStyle Not work with lockerService enable

Tags: chart.js, lightning

i use the `Version: 2.6.0` chart js. I have set the `pointStyle` with an image:

```
var icon = new Image();
'icon.src = 'https://assets0.uvcdn.com/pkg/shared/favicons/password-d904f06a67a7b29d489489d3a35f548b.png';
```

and into dataset object set `pointStyle: icon`.

This is not work in lightning with `lockerService` enable. Exist an workaround?

Thanks